# Is the direct sum in Maschke's Theorem an orthogonal decomposition?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, group-actions, coding-theory

I am reading a paper on coding theory, and it uses a statement, which was claimed to be a reformulation of Maschke's Theorem.  But I felt that was false...

Let's say $\mathcal(V):=\mathcal{F}_2^n$ is the big ambient space.  $\sigma \in S_n$ is a permutation of odd prime order $p$.  $\sigma$ acts on our ambient space by permuting the order of the coordinates.

Let $\mathcal{V}(\sigma)$ be the space in $\mathcal{V}$ that is fixed by the action of $\sigma$. (So those are the ones that have the same value on the orbit of $\sigma$.).  Below is what I think what the paper meant by it's a reformulation of Maschke's theorem.

Let $\pi$ be a projection from $\mathcal{V}$ onto $\mathcal{V}(\sigma)$, and let $H$ be the group generated by $\sigma$.  (So just $1, \sigma, \sigma^2, \dots$.)  Define

\begin{align*}
   \phi: \mathcal{V} &\rightarrow \mathcal{V}(\sigma) \\
x &\mapsto \sum_{g \in H} g \pi(g^{-1}x)
\end{align*}

Then it's easy to check $\phi$ is still a projection, and $\phi$ composed with the inclusion map is identity on $\mathcal{V}(\sigma)$.  By splitting lemma,

This uses the fact that $p$ is odd.  Since if $p$ is even, the sum will always be 0.

What confuses me is that the paper claimed that 
$$ \mathcal{V}  = \mathcal{V}(\sigma) \oplus \mathcal{V}(\sigma)^\bot$$ where $\mathcal{V}(\sigma)^\bot$ is the dual space of $\mathcal{V}(\sigma)$ using the usual inner product defined on $\mathbb{F}_2^n$.

My feeling is that those two decompositions are not necessarily the same one.  Or are they?  If so, is there a way to show that?

Comment: By splitting lemma,... ?

Comment: @FriederLadisch: Isn't $\dfrac{1}{\left|H\right|} = 1$ thanks to the fact that $\sigma$ has odd order and the base field is $\mathbb{F}_2$ ?

Comment: For the original question: Yeah, I'm not even sure whether the second decomposition is correct. Why is the sum direct?

Comment: OK, actually you can prove that the second decomposition is correct. But you'll have to use the concrete details of the construction. The permutation $\sigma$ has odd order, and thus each of its cycles has odd size. Consider each of these cycles as acting on its own subspace, and show that the decomposition on this particular subspace works; then take the direct sum. (In other words, reduce to the case when $\sigma$ is a cycle.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Yes, of course you're correct. My other remark was also misguided, so I deleted my comment.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: The second decomposition is correct even in a more general context: see the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: May be your initial feeling that the claim might not be correct comes from the fact that, for example, some cyclic codes are self-orthogonal? In other words, you may have seen $\sigma$-stable subspaces $V$ of the same ambient space with the property that $V\subseteq V^\perp$. In the present case $V(\sigma)$ is not just a random subspace stable under $\sigma$, but a more special beast. The difference coming from the fact that $V(\sigma)$ is fixed *elementwise* as opposed to just being a $\sigma$-stable subspace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The decompositions are the same because actually there is only one $H$-invariant complement to $\mathcal{V}(\sigma)$ in $V$. Consider $e = \sum_{g\in H} g$ as operator on $V$. Then $v\in \mathcal{V}(\sigma) = \operatorname{Fix}_V(H)$ iff $ev=v$, as is easy to show. So if $W$ is any complement to $\mathcal{V}(\sigma)$, and if $W$ is $H$-invariant, then $eW \subseteq W\cap \mathcal{V}(\sigma) = \{0\}$ and thus $W = (1-e)V$.
This means also that no matter what projection $\pi$ you start with, you will get $\phi = e$.

In your concrete situation, $\mathcal{V}(\sigma)^{\perp}$ is $H$-invariant because $\sigma$ acts "orthogonally" with respect to the inner product.

This can be done in a more general context: Suppose some finite group $H$ acts on some $F$-vector space $V$ and the characteristic of $F$ does not divide the group order $|H|$: Then $e = (1/|H|)\sum_{g\in H} g$ is the only $H$-invariant projection onto the fixed space of $H$ on $V$. Moreover, if $f\colon V\times V \to F$ is an $H$-invariant bilinear form, then $f(ev,w) = f(v,ew)$ and so $f(eV, (1-e)V) = 0$. Thus if $f$ is non-degenerate on $V$, then the restriction of $f$ to the fixed space is also non-degenerate.
Another remark is that the uniqueness above is a special case of the uniqueness of the decomposition of a semisimple module into its *homogeneous components*.

Comment: Thank you!  This perfectly answers my question and a bit more!